# Getting seasick from winterbash bumps on the meta front page

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013

Some people have been editing questions on meta. Many questions. Old questions. Obsolete questions. And they fill the front page. There was a flood of edits to old Area 51 questions a few days ago.

I suspect that this is due to people chasing hats. For next year, could the hat designers try to avoid incenting front-page noise generation.

Could we have 'too localized' back on Meta :-) so that we could close these when they resurface?

Comment: This is waaaaaay to localized to meta. Voting to close.

Comment: ;-) ....... :-P

Comment: That was my fault.  In a bizarre twist of fate, I created the [tag:badge-gaming] tag, and inadvertently gamed 3 badges in the process.

Comment: that tag link doesn't work very well, it goes to stackoverflow and whines.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.  Ignore the above, I meant [meta-tag:badge-gaming].  :o)

Comment: *I suspect that this is people chasing hats.* says someone with the Mr. Peanut Monopoly McDuck hat on his head when he says it.  :-)

Comment: As it happens, I'm way too lazy to edit 25 old questions to get a hat. I take the hats as they come.

Comment: "There was a flood of edits to old Area 51 questions a few days ago. I suspect that this is due to people chasing hats." - Eh, I doubt kiamlaluno was killing off the [meta-tag:area51-discussion] tag (which is what those edits were doing) for *hats*, but I can't say what the motivation was.

Comment: @TimStone especially because you can't earn hats on area 51 :)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Well, this was to questions *about* Area 51 posted here, but also true. :)

Comment: *I CAN GET A HAT BY BUMPING OLD META POSTS?!?* **WOOOOOOO!**

Answer (score 3):

This won't work in my opinion.

There will always be secret hats, and people will try anything to try and get them.

If those edits are good and improve the overall content, the hats did their job just fine. If the edits are bad (trivial or adding white spaces) then you should report it (flag should be enough) and the users will be warned not to repeat this. Hats are fun, but no excuse to bad behaviour.